# How to transfer files from remote to remote via ftp?

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, centos, cpanel

I want to transfer files between two servers , files size is aproximately 170GB.
On one server , there is Direct Admin control panel, and on the other one is Cpanel . 
I've ftp & ssh access on both servers. I know about scp command on ssh, but as I've tried it and I didn't succeed , I prefer to use ftp commands. Because there were some connection or other errors on ssh , so the transfer progress was stopping and I couldn't resume the progress by skipping already uploaded files. So what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rsync`, it will continue where it stopped.

Go to one of the servers and do:

```
rsync -avz other.server.com:/path/to/directory /where/to/save
```

You can omit `z` option if the data is not compressible.

This is with assumption that the user name on both servers is the same.
If not you will need to add `-e 'ssh -l login_name'` to the above command.

Comment: When I try to use rsync it returns an error , I think rsync isn't installed on the server where direct admin is installed.

Comment: @MostafaSafarian All host that use rsync must be installed rsync package. Try install on remote server rsync package. For best work if you don't know rsync try rsync -avvz --progress other.server.com:/path/to/directory /where/to/save for more verbosity and for see progress